# Is there a way to upvote comments?

Tags: support, comment, badges

I was looking at possible badges I could earn on CV. I think there was one where you could earn the badge by voting for a specified number of comments. I have seen numbers to the left of some comments. Do they represent votes? I have no idea what to do to vote for comments if it is possible.

Comment: Upvote this sample comment.

Comment: Thanks.  I did it for your comment and one other person must have too.

Comment: by the way I think you earned those upvotes.

Comment: See the [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites), under "**Reputation, badges and voting**" specifically the question [How does comment voting and flagging work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work).

Comment: Thanks Glen_b.  Andre Silva gave me the detail I wanted about upvoting comments.  I can see why we should be able to flag comments since some people might violate policy and use bad language.  I also noticed some comments being removed because book prices were mentioned.  That was probably done by a moderator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is. Hover over the left side of a comment and click in the up arrow to vote (try it in the sample comment I left under the question). Comments can't be downvoted. You will also see a flag beneath the up arrow; that is for flagging comments.

[Badges](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/badges) related to commenting are 'Commentator' (bronze) and 'Pundit' (silver). The latter is the one related to voting. One needs to write 10 comments and each of them receive at least 5 upvotes (yes, numbers on the left represent the amount of votes a comment received). I think the intent of  the Pundit badge is reward users who write useful comments. Likewise voting on regular posts, a user can't vote for his/her own comments.

There are no badges for upvoting comments.

Comment: Okay thank you.  I didn't remember clearly what I saw. There are many comments that I would like to vote for.  So it helps to know how to do it.  I make a lot of comments.  Many are helpful.  Probably if more people knew  this I might be getting more votes on comments.  I would like to try for the commentator badge.  Of course I shouldn't be able to upvote my own comments.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, you are welcome. I think you are aware, but if not, see that you already have [Commentator and Pundit in the main site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/11032/michael-chernick?tab=badges), and have 'Commentator' here on meta. So, keep participating in meta, and will get 'Pundit' soon. Good luck.

Comment: I achieved most of my badges on my first trip to CV.  That was 2011 and 2012 when I was very active here.  I resumed activity in November 2016 and am becoming active and reacquainted with the rules.  I appreciate your politeness and patience with me.  I hadn't checked.  I think I have earned one or two badges since returning in November.  Over the years it is entirely possible that I earned some additional badges (probably not many) over those years as others reviewed my posts.